# How to use std::log as a functional?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++11, logging

I try to pass std::log as a functional argument, but it seems that there are overloaded implementations of std::log and the compiler failed to resolve it. Codes:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template <typename FOper>
double Eval(FOper fOper, double X)
{
    return fOper(X);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::function<double(double)> fPlus1 = std::bind(std::plus<double>(), 1.0, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout<<Eval(fPlus1, 10.0)<<std::endl;
    //  how to write this fLog ?
    //std::function<double(double)> fLog = std::log;
    //std::function<double(double)> fLog = std::log<double>;
    std::cout<<Eval(fLog, 10.0)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The complier prompts an error message if I uncomment either line of the definition of fLog:

```
error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<double(doubl
e)>' requested
```

Comment: FYI: Names like `_This` and `__this` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: You have to wrap `std::log`. The fact that it is an overloaded function (and not a template) prevents you to use `std::log<double>` as a functor. Something like `[](double x) -> { return std::log(x); }` is enough.

Comment: To @Xeo: I have changed the naming style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Xeo explained, it is possible to get it to work even when the function is overloaded using an explicit cast. However, since you're using std::function already (which is a C++11 feature), you might as well just use a lambda expression as initializer:

```
function<double(double)> fLog = [](double x){return std::log(x);};
```

This is preferable in C++11 because it avoids overloading issues. Also, it is more efficient than wrapping a function pointer because it saves one level of indirection and therefore allows the lambda's body to be inlined into the internal wrapper object's function call operator.

It should probably be stressed that the use of std::function in your example is unnecessary since Eval is already a function template and the type parameter FOper can exactly match the type of the function object without the need to wrap it inside std::function. So, if you don't need the type erasure you get by using std::function, you could just as well write

```
template <typename FOper>
double Eval(FOper fOper, double X)
{
    return fOper(X);
}

int main()
{
    auto flog = [](double x){return std::log(x);};
    std::cout << Eval(flog, 10.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Good style! But the compiler can usually perform constant value optimization on a function pointer passed into an algorithm, and simple implementations of `std::function` will *always* use an indirect call because the complexity of that class may require a virtual dispatch before it even decides a lambda or function pointer needs to be followed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Sure, std::function has some levels of indirection (two I think) which cannot be circumvented. From what I can tell, using a function pointer would add another level whereas the lambda's function call operator could be inlined in the last level (the std::function's internal wrapper). But I don't know what the actual runtime difference is. I guess the lambda version is better -- at least in case std::log is a compiler intrinsic.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `auto fLog` to avoid the indirection levels of `std::function`?

Comment: @Kleist: Yes, and since the OP is using templates anyways, he may aswell just pass that or the function pointer directly, but maybe the code in the question is just an example and the OP actually needs to store the function, in which case `std::function` makes sense.

Comment: @Kleist: Sure. But I assumed that there is a reason for using std::function in the first place. But you're right. In the context of the Eval function template it should be mentioned that std::function is unnecessary in this case. I'll add this bit to the answer ...

Comment: I use the explicit type `std::function` rather than `auto` just wanting to give more clearly type definition of the variable. Anyway, I did not aware of the possible optimization for indirect function call. Thanks to all you guys.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be to simply cast it:

```
typedef double (*log_d)(double);
std::function<double(double)> fLog = static_cast<log_d>(std::log);
```

With the cast, you hand the compiler a context in which the overloaded function is used, and as such will get the correct function pointer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
typedef double (*logtype)(double);
std::function<double(double)> fLog = (logtype) std::log;
```

The cast will help compiler to select the correct overload.

You can also write this:

```
double (*fLog )(double) =  std::log; //i.e don't use std::function

std::cout<<Eval(fLog, 10.0)<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that something like this on its own has no meaning:

`std::bind( std::log, _1 );` // cannot resolve. bind what function? What will _1 be passed as?

log is not a template so you can't call `std::log<double>` in there.

You can make your own template though, that will resort to log:

```
template< typename T >
T logT( T t )
{
   return std::log( t );
}
```

and now you can use logT in your code.

`std::bind( logT<double>, _ 1 )` // should work.

You could of course make fLog a function pointer to logT if you want. With C++11 you can use auto etc. to not have to type out its type by hand.